# Притяжательные местоимения для чайников!

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения

Когда стоит использовать притяжательные местоимения (например: его, наш и т. д.)? Понятно что есть разные ситуации, но вот как точно понять, уместно ли?

Примеры:
Ты не замечаешь **своих** ошибок.
Забыли ключ доступа? К сожалению **его** нельзя восстановить.
У **них** много работы.
Это **мой** че­мо­дан, мне нужно уло­жить сюда **мои** вещи.

Или вот у Пушкина:
Прими с улыб­кою, **мой** друг,
Сво­бод­ной музы при­но­ше­нье…

Comment: Не стоит лепить метки просто до кучи. Ставьте только те, в отношении которых уверены, что они относятся к делу.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос слишком общо поставлен.
Любое слово стоит использовать тогда и только тогда, когда оно нужно автору для выражения мысли, передачи акцентов или хотя бы по формальным требованиям грамматики.

Избыточное использование притяжательных местоимений в русском объясняют - помимо прочего - влиянием английского, где такие местоимения по сути являются единственной альтернативой артиклю.
В русском необходимости в артикле нет, как нет и самого артикля, поэтому местоимения не нужны там, где они ничего не добавляют к пониманию фразы, не выражают никаких дополнительных чувств или интонации, не нужны по требованиям стилистики или стихотворного размера. Хотя последнее основание - тоже не лучший поэтический выбор, заполнение местоимениями дыр в метрической структуре очков стиху не добавляет.

Вряд ли есть какое-то принципиально иное обоснование. Давать примеры сознательно избегаю, ибо все оценки весьма относительны.
А что касается ваших, давайте посмотрим.

> Ты не замечаешь **своих** ошибок.

Здесь это важное слово, более чем уместно.

> Забыли ключ доступа? К сожалению его нельзя восстановить.
>   У них много работы.

Это вообще из другой сферы. "Его" и "(у) них" здесь местоимения личные, а не притяжательные. Для них и правила другие. Здесь безусловно нужны.

> Это мой че­мо­дан, мне нужно уло­жить сюда мои вещи.

Целесообразность использования в первом случае сомнений не вызывает (на "мой" падает логическое ударение), хотя в определенном контексте и его можно опустить. Во втором же случае сильно зависит от авторской мысли. Если, например, чемодан по каким-то причинам оказался набит **чужими** вещами, то второе "мой" тоже безусловно имеет право на существование. Если же принадлежность укладываемых вещей сомнения не вызывает, то второе "мой" совсем не обязательно и вероятно лишнее.

Или вот у Пушкина:

> Прими с улыб­кою, мой друг,
>   Сво­бод­ной музы при­но­ше­нье…

У Пушкина ничего лишнего быть не может по определению.  )))
Шероховатости, разумеется, можно найти и у него, но в целом Пушкин - это и есть эталон тогдашней литературной речи, ставший во многом эталоном и языка современного. Другого, объективного? эталона просто не существует. Напиши Пушкин тогда по-другому, другими бы были и наши критерии оценки.

Впрочем, в данном случае "мой друг" поддается и вполне объективной оценке.  "Мой друг" - устойчивое выражение при обращении, к тому же точно соответствует в аналогичных случаях употребляемому, французскому (и не только).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Если вместо этого: Ты не замечаешь своих ошибок. Вот так: Ты пропускаешь ошибки. Смысл ведь остался и без лишних слов.

Comment: Антон, Вы, наверно, подумали, что это я Вам ответил, а на самом деле ответил behemothus, смотрите справа. Я только исправил опечатки в его ответе.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  А вот не правьте, чтобы не подумали лишнего. ))))

Comment: *Если вместо этого: Ты не замечаешь своих ошибок. Вот так: Ты пропускаешь ошибки. Смысл ведь остался и без лишних слов* -  если не знать контекста, то смысл сильно изменился. Откуда видно что "Я" пропускаю свои ошибки? Вон Артём Луговой, случается, как раз **мои** ошибки пропускает когда правит. *Правда редко, обычно ловит сразу, раньше чем я их сам успеваю поправить.*